# Register Battery Changed broadcast in Android service

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm starting a service from an Activity. The service registers for Battery Changed broadcast Receiver. I receive broadcasts as long as the screen is ON. Once the screen is turned OFF, I stop receiving broadcasts, however, the service doesn't die.

My activity code,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context = this.getApplicationContext();     

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,BatteryStatusService.class);


    startService(intent);
}
```

and my service code,

```
public class BatteryStatusService extends Service{

private final static String TAG = BatteryStatusService.class.getSimpleName();
private BroadcastReceiver timeTickReceiver;//changeReceiver;
private boolean registered = false;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    BatteryStatusService getService() {
        return BatteryStatusService.this;
    }
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
    Log.i(TAG,"Starting service");

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Constants.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);     
    timeTickReceiver = new TimeTickReceiver();

    this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(timeTickReceiver, filter);
    registered = true;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Log.d(TAG,"Stopping service");  
if(registered){

        this.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(timeTickReceiver);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mBinder;
}

public class TimeTickReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String action = null;   
    private  final String TAG = TimeTickReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        action = intent.getAction();        




        if(action.equals(Constants.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)){                


            Log.d(TAG,"I got action = "+action);


                                }           
        }       
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

use `AlarmManager` and get last broadcasted level with

```
Intent BATTERYintent=this.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

However there are mobiles where it would work either. I have t-mobile MOVE which will not update battery value/broadcast no matter what in sleep mode...  but most mobiles will do it as they should

by the way dont listen to dcanh121  there are cases when u need to get battery level even when phone is in sleepmode.

Answer (score 0):

> Once the screen is turned OFF, I stop receiving broadcasts, however, the service doesn't die.

When the screen is turned off, shortly thereafter the device goes into sleep mode. Your code does not execute again until something wakes up the device from sleep mode.

Also:

- You do not need to use `getApplicationContext()` here
- You do not need a `Binder` here, since you are not binding to the service, so just have `onBind()` return `null`
- You need to have some code somewhere to stop this service, so it does not run forever

Comment: You are right, the device goes into sleep mode, but how do I still receive the broadcasts? thanks.

Comment: @dcanh121: Ideally, you don't. You can use a `WakeLock` to prevent sleep mode, but keeping the CPU on all of the time just to receive battery updates would be unprofessional, since it will drain the battery much, much faster. You should start getting the updates again automatically when the user turns their phone on again -- please leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try by using `onResume()` and `onPause()`

Comment: I want to use it in a service, and I want to listen to the changes even if the screen is off. It basically want to know when the battery level is changed (screen locked/unlocked).

Comment: Try by registering an Intent `(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)` in `onEnabled()` or `onReceive` or wherever you want to. Then use a Broadcast Receiver to receive that change.